# HTTP or HTTPS for a torrent tracker?

Tags: http, bittorrent, https

I use [bttrack](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/bittorrent/bttrack.bittorrent.1.en.html) as a private torrent tracker.
I don't see any HTTPS option. Does HTTPS matter for a torrent tracker?
My question is about security (not performance) but I accept any other information/suggestion.

Comment: It's common to fix HTTPS for a tracker by using a **reverse proxy** in front of it. Nginx is often used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of-course https matters - any data sent over http is not encrypted, so could be intercepted.   This would include (possibly hashed) login credentials if required.   It would presumably also allow people monitoring the tracker to determine who is downloading what parts of what torrents, which could provide evidence of wrong-doing.